# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while executing in TestNG

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am new to TestNG and I was trying my first test case with it.
It`s a simple case to print a statement, but everytime I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException as you can see in attached image.

Help me out. [image: Image with Project Structure, code and error]

Comment: set your code here +pom

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/206

Comment: @juherr, Thanks a lot .
It worked after uninstalling M2E. hurrey.